# Exporting value to specific line and column in a text file

Tags: r

I'd like to export random value defined in R as vector (or any other object) to a specific location in a text file. With the use of `read.fwf` I managed to read the data that is not csv or tab delineated (based on location in file), but no I can not find a suitable way to write/export some random value in the selected (defined) line/row and column in a txt file. I would appreciate any help or suggestions. I was looking to `write.table, sink` and also some other options for data export, but none of them worked or at least I was not able to complete the task ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `read.fwf` if you just want to replace specific characters. Instead, scan in the file line by line as a vector of character strings. Then you can use `substring<-` to replace specific positions by line and column.

Here's a simple example:

```
mydat <- scan(text='1234567890\n2345678901\n3456789012', what='character')
mydat
# [1] "1234567890" "2345678901" "3456789012"
substring(mydat[2],5,5) <- 'X'
mydat
# [1] "1234567890" "2345X78901" "3456789012"
substring(mydat[3],1,1) <- 'Y'
mydat
# [1] "1234567890" "2345X78901" "Y456789012"
```

The result can be written back to file using `writeLines`:

```
> writeLines(mydat)
1234567890
2345X78901
Y456789012
```